# Alfresco document-derived content is missing <content>

Tags: alfresco, cmis, alfresco-share

I've created a custom content type derived from document. I am trying to use CMIS to query my Alfresco server (tried with 4.2.b and 4.2.c) programmatically for my documents using python [cmislib](http://chemistry.apache.org/python/cmislib.html). I have a pyramid server that takes REST calls and sends them to my Alfresco server using CMIS.

I get this error:

```
2013-04-11 11:19:25,526 | ERROR | Exception when serving /access_manager/search_noauth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hbrown/.virtualenvs/access_manager_master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/waitress-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/waitress/channel.py", line 329, in service
    task.service()
[...]
  File "/home/hbrown/workspace/spt/access_manager/access_manager/views/search.py", line 223, in cmis_main
    for result in repo.query(whole_query)
  File "/home/hbrown/.virtualenvs/access_manager_master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmislib/model.py", line 2467, in getContentStream
    assert(len(contentElements) == 1), 'Expected to find exactly one atom:content element.'
AssertionError: Expected to find exactly one atom:content element.
```

I am using [getContentStream()](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/cmislib/trunk/src/cmislib/atompub_binding.py) to retrieve content. Based on the code comment, I'd say it is the correct API call:

```
    >>> doc.getName()
    u'sample-b.pdf'
    >>> o = open('tmp.pdf', 'wb')
    >>> result = doc.getContentStream()
    >>> o.write(result.read())
    >>> result.close()
    >>> o.close()
    >>> import os.path
    >>> os.path.getsize('tmp.pdf')
    117248
```

The python code in cmislib clearly expects the document to have XML that includes an element named `content`, and mine does not.

The calling code looks like this:

```
from cmislib import CmisClient

SERVER = "localhost"
url = "http://{0}:8080/alfresco/cmisatom".format(SERVER)
client = CmisClient(url, 'admin', 'alfresco')
repo = client.defaultRepository
results = repo.query("select * from wg:bulletin")
print results[0].getContentStream().read()
```

The XML being operated on in `getContentStream` looks like this:

```
<atom:entry>
    <atom:author>
        <atom:name/>
    </atom:author>
    <atom:id>http://chemistry.apache.org/aWQtMQ==</atom:id>
    <atom:published>2013-04-12T03:22:38Z</atom:published>
    <atom:title>Query Result id-1</atom:title>
    <app:edited>2013-04-12T03:22:38Z</app:edited>
    <atom:updated>2013-04-12T03:22:38Z</atom:updated>
    <cmisra:object xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/">
        <cmis:properties>
            <cmis:propertyInteger displayName="Content Stream Length" localName="contentStreamLength" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamLength" queryName="b.cmis:contentStreamLength">
                <cmis:value>249</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyInteger>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Object Type Id" localName="objectTypeId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId" queryName="b.cmis:objectTypeId">
                <cmis:value>D:wg:bulletin</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Version Series Checked Out By" localName="versionSeriesCheckedOutBy" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy" queryName="b.cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy"/>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Version Series Checked Out Id" localName="versionSeriesCheckedOutId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId" queryName="b.cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId"/>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Version series id" localName="versionSeriesId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId" queryName="b.cmis:versionSeriesId">
                <cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/1cd2053d-1fc4-4e85-b780-ba80284f0841</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:account" localName="account" propertyDefinitionId="wg:account" queryName="b.wg:account"/>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Version Label" localName="versionLabel" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel" queryName="b.cmis:versionLabel">
                <cmis:value>1.0</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="Is Latest Version" localName="isLatestVersion" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isLatestVersion" queryName="b.cmis:isLatestVersion">
                <cmis:value>true</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="Is Version Series Checked Out" localName="isVersionSeriesCheckedOut" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut" queryName="b.cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut">
                <cmis:value>false</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Last Modified By" localName="lastModifiedBy" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModifiedBy" queryName="b.cmis:lastModifiedBy">
                <cmis:value>admin</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Created by" localName="createdBy" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:createdBy" queryName="b.cmis:createdBy">
                <cmis:value>admin</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyDateTime displayName="wg:displayUntil" localName="displayUntil" propertyDefinitionId="wg:displayUntil" queryName="b.wg:displayUntil"/>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Alfresco Node Ref" localName="nodeRef" propertyDefinitionId="alfcmis:nodeRef" queryName="b.alfcmis:nodeRef">
                <cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/1cd2053d-1fc4-4e85-b780-ba80284f0841</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:email" localName="email" propertyDefinitionId="wg:email" queryName="b.wg:email"/>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="wg:isActive" localName="isActive" propertyDefinitionId="wg:isActive" queryName="b.wg:isActive">
                <cmis:value>false</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:username" localName="username" propertyDefinitionId="wg:username" queryName="b.wg:username"/>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="Is Latest Major Version" localName="isLatestMajorVersion" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isLatestMajorVersion" queryName="b.cmis:isLatestMajorVersion">
                <cmis:value>true</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Content Stream Id" localName="contentStreamId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamId" queryName="b.cmis:contentStreamId">
                <cmis:value>store://2013/4/10/15/29/20b185d0-afae-4a7f-a06e-58eab399bdc9.bin</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Name" localName="name" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name" queryName="b.cmis:name">
                <cmis:value>.pythonrc</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Content Stream MIME Type" localName="contentStreamMimeType" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamMimeType" queryName="b.cmis:contentStreamMimeType">
                <cmis:value>text/plain</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyDateTime displayName="Creation Date" localName="creationDate" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:creationDate" queryName="b.cmis:creationDate">
                <cmis:value>2013-04-10T15:29:18.146-04:00</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyDateTime>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Change token" localName="changeToken" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:changeToken" queryName="b.cmis:changeToken"/>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:state" localName="state" propertyDefinitionId="wg:state" queryName="b.wg:state"/>
            <cmis:propertyDateTime displayName="wg:displayFrom" localName="displayFrom" propertyDefinitionId="wg:displayFrom" queryName="b.wg:displayFrom"/>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Checkin Comment" localName="checkinComment" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:checkinComment" queryName="b.cmis:checkinComment"/>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:application" localName="application" propertyDefinitionId="wg:application" queryName="b.wg:application"/>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Object Id" localName="objectId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId" queryName="b.cmis:objectId">
                <cmis:value>workspace://SpacesStore/1cd2053d-1fc4-4e85-b780-ba80284f0841;1.0</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="Is Immutable" localName="isImmutable" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isImmutable" queryName="b.cmis:isImmutable">
                <cmis:value>false</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyBoolean displayName="Is Major Version" localName="isMajorVersion" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isMajorVersion" queryName="b.cmis:isMajorVersion">
                <cmis:value>true</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyBoolean>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="wg:institution" localName="institution" propertyDefinitionId="wg:institution" queryName="b.wg:institution"/>
            <cmis:propertyId displayName="Base Type Id" localName="baseTypeId" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId" queryName="b.cmis:baseTypeId">
                <cmis:value>cmis:document</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString displayName="Content Stream Filename" localName="contentStreamFileName" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamFileName" queryName="b.cmis:contentStreamFileName">
                <cmis:value>.pythonrc</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyDateTime displayName="Last Modified Date" localName="lastModificationDate" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModificationDate" queryName="b.cmis:lastModificationDate">
                <cmis:value>2013-04-10T15:29:23.384-04:00</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyDateTime>
        </cmis:properties>
    </cmisra:object>
</atom:entry>
```

There is clearly no XML element named `content` here for the python code to extract.

Is this a misconfiguration of my custom content document or is it a change in CMIS that cmislib does not track or am I calling the wrong API function to get the content or something else?

---

Later: the minimum change to fix this is to make calls to either `reload` or `getAllowableActions`.

This was the original code:

```
def cmis_main(props, settings):
    """
    Create a CMIS query based on props and execute against Alfresco
    """
    def cmis_query(props, mapping):
        """
        Create CMIS query of AND-separated OR-clauses
        """
        # Code that formats a query string from dictionaries...

    cmis_mapping = {
        # Dictionary config for call to cmis_query
        # Nothing to see here. Move on.
        "app_sids": {
            "where_fmt": IN_WHERE_FMT,
            "key": "{0}:application".format(CMIS_NAMESPACE),
            "fn": set_format,
        },
    }

    cmis_url, cmis_user, cmis_password = cmis_args(settings)
    cmisclient = CmisClient(cmis_url, cmis_user, cmis_password)
    repo = cmisclient.getDefaultRepository()
    whole_query = cmis_query(props, cmis_mapping)
    logger.debug(whole_query)

    return [
        {
            'name': result.name,
            'content': result.getContentStream().read(),
            'content_mime_type': result.properties["cmis:contentStreamMimeType"],
        }
        for result in repo.query(whole_query)
    ]
```

And it was broken. So I changed the code to this:

```
    results = list(repo.query(whole_query))
    for result in results:
        print(result.getAllowableActions())
        # or: result.reload()

    return [
        {
            'name': result.name,
            'content': result.getContentStream().read(),
            'content_mime_type': result.properties["cmis:contentStreamMimeType"],
        }
        for result in results
    ]
```

And it worked. I changed it to this:

```
    results = list(repo.query(whole_query))
    for result in results:
        pass

    return [
        {
            'name': result.name,
            'content': result.getContentStream().read(),
            'content_mime_type': result.properties["cmis:contentStreamMimeType"],
        }
        for result in results
    ]
```

And it broke. So the XML does not appear to be fully loaded in the CMISLIB object.

Comment: Do you happen to have the XML content that *is* being returned to hand? And also the code that you are using to retrieve the document, and then the content?

Comment: @Will Abson: I have provided much more detailed code and output to aid in the analysis/spelunking.

Comment: This is very strange. I cannot recreate this on my machine using Alfresco 4.2.c, cmislib 0.5.1, and objects using my own custom content model. Can you share your content model, or at least tell me about wg:bulletin? For example, does it inherit from cm:content directly? Are you using any aspects? Also, what does results[0].getAllowableActions()['canGetContentStream'] return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing results[0].reload() before calling getContentStream(). That shouldn't be required but it may force the object to reload with the content element.

Comment: Revision: I ended up having to reload every result, not just the first. I tried `repo.reload()`, `resultset.reload()`, `resultset[0].reload` (when there was at least one result). Only calling `reload` on every result kept me from having errors. Accordingly, I put out this pull request on github: https://github.com/apache/chemistry-cmislib/pull/1